# node net socket timeout error on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, ibm-cloud

This is my server side code which has been hosted on IBM Bluemix,

```
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer((c) => { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', () => {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, () => { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

I am using below code as client on local,

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx';
var PORT = xxxx;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client
    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');

});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    // Close the client socket completely
    client.destroy();

});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

When I run, It throws error Like.

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14) vivek@vivek-Latitude-E6220:/var/www/html/test/NODE/net$ node client.js
>   events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)

When I run the server code on local, It works perfect. Kindly help me to find the error.

Comment: Is the specified port open from Bluemix? Or is a server, client, or network firewall blocking the connection?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy. that particular port is not opened.  I found that was the problem. But I didn't know how to open that port. so I hosted my app in aws and opened that port. Now it is working. If you know how to open the port on IBM Bluemix. Kindly post it as answer.

Comment: I have no experience with Bluemix, sorry. I expect there is a way, but I don't know their system at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on the port that Bluemix assigns for your application.  Bluemix will assign your application a port and you will need to bind on that port.  Bluemix will load balance to your application and have your application available on ports `443` and `80`.

You can get the port with the following code.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8124;
```

Also you don't need to bind to a host either.

I modified your code below.

```
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer((c) => { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', () => {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 8124;
server.listen(port, () => { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `read ECONNRESET` Error in your server, when client destroy the socket.

you can catch using

```
c.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('SOCKET  ERROR : ' , err);
});
```

you can avoid the crash this way.

working version for me, based on your code

server.js

```
const net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
      console.log('client connected');
      c.on('end', function(c) {
        console.log('sendHomeKeytoIosDevice : ERROR : ' + c);
      });
      c.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('sendHomeKeytoIosDevice : ERROR : ' + err);
      });
      c.write('hello\r\n');
      c.pipe(c);
});


server.listen(8124,function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Client.js

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 8124;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client
    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');

});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    // Close the client socket completely
    client.destroy();

});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think client is not making any connection with server. In that case we can not use error event. @Oxi

Comment: i tried it locally, and its working. i will modify my answer with the code i did

Comment: In local it is working for me too. But on server(IBM Bluemix) It is not.